# Created a React App with a blog feature, the blog posts won't display, can anyone see why?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

As part of a project I am working on, I'm making a blog page to our react app. However, I am having trouble getting the blog posts to display.

I have a call setup on my express backend for retrieving all my posts from my MYSQL database as such:

```
// Route to get all posts
app.get("/api/get", (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM posts", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.send(result)
    });
});
```

And in the front end I'm using this code to get the data from that API call:

```
const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:3002/api/get").then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    setPostList(data.data)
  });
}, [])
```

To display the posts I'm using this code here:

```
<div className="PostContainer">
  {postList.map((val, key) => {
    return (
      <div className="Post" >
        <h1 className="post-title" onClick={() => (navigate(`/post/${val.id}`))}>{val.title}</h1>
        <p>{val.post_text.length > 300 ? val.post_text.substring(0, 300) + " ..." : val.post_text}</p>
        <h4>{val.user_name}</h4>
        <button className="like_btn" onClick={(() => LikePost(val.id))}>Like</button>

        <h5>Likes: {val.likes}</h5>
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

This all seems fine to me but obviously something is wrong somewhere as none of the posts display.

Comment: Does it appear in the console after you call `console.log(data)`?

Comment: *"something is wrong somewhere"* - Your next step is to do some debugging.  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the component in question, is `postList` ever successfully populated?  When you debug, where specifically in the expected order of operations does an operation first fail or produce an unexpected result?

Comment: res.send sends a string, but you expecting a json array. should you be converting your mysql results to json like res.json or something?

Comment: @David thanks for the advice, nothing seems to be the issue with the backend, however after just realising my browser has a console (rookie mistake), i've found that it is throwing an error when i open the blog page. "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3001/api/get. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200." is the error that is being given, going to do some research into it but if you know what that error is that'd be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After closer inspection, I found the console on my browser was throwing this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:3001/api/get. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

After doing some more research I found I had to include some code so my backend would send the information to the frontend. This is the code I implemented:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();});
```

This has fixed my issues and the blog posts now display with the correct information.